# How to let input numbers are saved in a text file

Tags: python, text

Make a new file called inputted_number.txt. Modify the created code so that all the valid input is saved in that file.
My codes are below:

```
txt = open("sqroot2_10kdigits.txt")

while True:
    number = input("Enter four digits (q to quit): ")
    if number.lower() == 'q':
        break
    elif len(number) != 4 or not number.isdigit():
        print("Please enter four numbers")
        continue
    pos = txt.find(number)
    if pos > -1:
        print(
            f'The digits {number} appear in the first '
            '10,000 characters of the square root of 2.'
            f'They appear starting on the {pos}th '
            'character after the decimal.'
        )
    else:
        print(
            f'Sorry, the digits {number} do not appear '
            'in the first 10,000 characters of the '
            'square root of 2.'
        )
    
#Make a new file. Please check here

with open('inputted_number.txt.', 'w') as filehandle:
    filehandle.write('3210\n3222\n4771\n')
```

Anyone can give me some ideas about how to modify the second part of Making a new file called inputted_number.txt. so that all the valid input is saved in that file? (the while-loop codes are no problem.) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create list with valid numbers and write that list in file at the end:

After you check and found that `number` is valid you can `append` number in `numbers` list.

check below code.

```
with open("sqroot2_10kdigits.txt", 'r') as fp:
    txt = fp.read()
numbers = []
while True:
    number = input("Enter four digits (q to quit): ")
    if number.lower() == 'q':
        break
    elif len(number) != 4 or not number.isdigit():
        print("Please enter four numbers")
        continue
    numbers.append(number)
    pos = txt.find(number)
    if pos > -1:
        print(
            f'The digits {number} appear in the first '
            '10,000 characters of the square root of 2.'
            f'They appear starting on the {pos}th '
            'character after the decimal.'
        )
    else:
        print(
            f'Sorry, the digits {number} do not appear '
            'in the first 10,000 characters of the '
            'square root of 2.'
        )

# Make a new file. Please check here

with open('inputted_number.txt.', 'w') as filehandle:
    filehandle.writelines(numbers)
```

Comment: pos = txt.find(number)
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'find' .... Hey! how to solve this error please, thank you so much!

Comment: I guess this line" numbers.append(number)"

Comment: @ssssmaner  txt is file reader object in your case. You can use txt=txt.read() or check the updated answer

Comment: use txt=txt.read()  to replace   numbers.append(number)? but in that file without my input number

Comment: @ssssmaner dont change numbers.append check the updated answer